# CodeIgniter session class automatically stores session for anonymous users

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm new to CI and use [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)'s  default [session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) to authenticate my users, I also use MySQL to store sessions, something that seems strange is that CI **automatically** creates sessions for **anonymous users** at first time they hit any page of the website, I read the [documentation of the class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) and found out that CI automatically creates the session when the session class is initialized but  didn't find any solution to disable this .

Actually this extra write on the database causes overhead on the machine which runs the website.

Is it possible to disable this feature of CI session class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've noticed is normal, every new user will start a session if the Session library is loaded. There is no need to worry about it, Codeigniter will remove unused table rows, so it will not overflow.

> Note: The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html